# Rf/voltage powermeter

Tags: arduino, rf, raspberry-pi

I want to start a project and i'm clueless even after reading a lot.

I have an rf route with some rf components/equipments connected, analog signals going through (wired). My goal is to check the dB of the rf wave in a certain frequency and bandwidth and show it on a gui eventually in my computer.
I can check it in a spectrum analyzer but my goal is to show it on my computer.
I was thinking about connecting arduino microcontroller/power sensor in each point I want to check, in order to do this I need RF IN input and RF OUT output to continue the chain without breaking it. I also need to consider the attenuation comes with the microcontroller/sensor I connect.

After some more research, I found out I can convert the analog signal to digital with raspberrypi and then measure the voltage going in the computer with an rs232 cable. Then how can I convert it back to analog?
Is it necessary or there is an other way?

I need an advice how do I start with it?

-What components do I need, microcontroller/power sensor? And which one exactly is fitting my criteria?
-Where can I learn to code these specific components and rf waves?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Before you can design anything , you have to search for explanations on how they work. Then you decide all the variables and tolerances for a design spec before the component selection. So you have a bit of learning to do that is your job.  All the answers are out there on the web, you just need to learn how to search

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=rf+power+meter+design&client=firefox-b-e&sxsrf=ALeKk03vRF_KdXP35pxp8V5eZkbTT954eg:1613533579744&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF7-n-gPDuAhVnMlkFHVb1D2cQ_AUoAXoECAUQAw&biw=1352&bih=765

Comment: Already searched google and I know how it works, still didn’t manage to understand how to make this project..

Comment: You have to learn how RF works and meters work first over different f ranges. I linked many examples to follow. We don’t know what you want.there are too many variables.

Comment: I know RF good enough, I just cant manage to find the right equipment to buy to program on, should it be raspberry pi or arduino board? and if so, which one? I need it in a certain frequency I would choose and a certain bandwidth.

Comment: If you know RF then you can use an analog meter or a DMM after the cap, otherwise this is not an RF power meter problem but just a measurement interface issue

Comment: Ok that's something I can aim to , let's say i'm getting analog meter instead of a spectrum analyzer , how can I program on it and make it to a GUI remotley eventually? and can I continue my rfchain even with the analong meter connected with no issues except some attenuation right?

Comment: use your meter to GUI converter toolbox right after you study more about interfacing

Comment: Perhaps you could read lots of EDN magazine design articles to improve your wisdom of power meters and interfacing by reading the theory of operation.  Directional couplers are often used with hot-carrier (Sch.) diodes to measure output and reflected power